# Why does this C program not work after the while loop?

Tags: c

I am writing a command line C program that simulates the [Monty Hall Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem), but I am having trouble with a particular section of my code, where the program simply prompts the user to input the number door they would like to open, it gets the input and makes sure it is valid:

```
printf("Please enter the door you would like to choose! (Door 1, 2 or 3)\n\nDoor ");

char init_input[255];

int selection;
int valid_input = 0;
while(valid_input == 0)
{   
    gets(init_input);
    int len = strlen(init_input);
    while(len != 1)
    {
        printf("Please choose either door 1, 2 or 3\n\n");
        printf("Door ");
        gets(init_input);
        len = strlen(init_input);
    }
    int valid_input = 0;
    char input = init_input[0];
    switch(input)
    {
        case('1'):
        {
            selection = 1;
            valid_input = 1;
            printf("Door 1\n");
            break;
        }
        case('2'):
        {
            selection = 2;
            valid_input = 1;
            printf("Door 2\n");
            break;

        }
        case('3'):
        {
            selection = 3;
            valid_input = 1;
            printf("Door 3\n");
            break;


        }
        default:
        {
            printf("\nPlease choose either door 1, 2 or 3\n\nDoor ");
            break;
        }
    }
}

printf("\nYou chose Door %d, now I will reveal one of the doors that has a goat behind it:\n\n", selection);
```

The program works fine until you input any of the valid door numbers: 1, 2 or 3, it doesn't crash but doesn't print the desired output after the while loop and continue with the program. However, the name of the door chosen is printed when I input a valid number, which suggests that it isn't anything to do with the switch statement.

Comment: Why don't you simply input an integer directly and then have the validation checks , if it is something other than 1,2 or 3 , let the user input again.

Comment: I want to make the program idiot proof- so that if the user enters something other than an integer it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're shadowing `valid_input` from within the `while` loop scope:

```
int valid_input = 0;
while (valid_input == 0) {
    // ...
    int valid_input = 0;     // remove this
}
```

When you write to or read from `valid_input` in the loop, you are reading from the one declared in the loop, not outside of it. So, the `valid_input` your loop checks for actually never changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Can't believe I missed that! Now I can finally move on with the program...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program, you absolutely positively should learn to use a debugger. Most compilers have a reasonably nice one these days. Step through your code. You should be able to determine where it goes wrong. And you might learn a few other unexpected things about your code as well.

I can't immediately see why the loop wouldn't exit given input of a valid door number. But, then again, I'm not 100% sure exactly where to look.

(BTW, I've created test programs of the "Monty Hall problem". It's true and here's why: By revealing one of the doors, you are provided additional information about the door you did not choose. However, since they will never reveal the door you originally chose, you do not learn anything about that door. By switching, your odds of winning become 1/2 instead of 1/3.)

Comment: I know- currently I am using a text editor with GCC in the command line and have know idea how to debug with this. Every time I have tried using a IDE (Visual C++, Netbeans, Codeblocks to name a few), I have been given errors that were not present when compiling with my current method, so I have avoided using an IDE for the time being until I move on to bigger projects.